# Error posting content on Facebook using gem (koala) on ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

In my ruby on rails application i am using Koala gem to post contents like message/link on facebook. But while trying to post its giving following error message:

> You've already posted this. Posting the same content repeatedly on
>   Facebook isn't allowed

I am however posting different content each time.

My code:

```
 auth_token="token" # this token i am getting from facebook graph-api with publish_actions permission.
 @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(auth_token)
 message=@graph.put_connections("me", "feed",:message=> "welcome")
```

Could you tell me that what would be the exact problem? and how to resolve it?

Comment: @Amadan. what do you mean?

Comment: @Amadan Not only "welcome". i am trying to post different messages like "hi", "hello", "hello world." For all it's giving the same error message and also nothing get posted on fb wall.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem too, its not an issue with koala its a facebook problem. I was trying to post stuff on my own wall using the facebook graph explorer, I accidentally posted the same message several times. As a result facebook flagged it as spam and as a result blocked all messages from applications from being posted onto my feed.

I had to click on the notification which mentioned 'please check your recent posts and likes to make sure their yours', press some buttons saying that everything was fine, and after that I was able to use the facebook graph api to send posts to my page.

So this problem is caused by posting multiple identical messages to a users account, causing facebook to categorise your app as spammy, from that point onwards even if the messages are different you'll get the same error message.